# how to extract data from linux server to web page?

Tags: linux, html, fetch

I have some data stored in a Linux server which can only be viewed via terminal or ssh. I decided to create a web page which will show the data in a table format.

One of which I think of is and going to try: Export CSV - Import into Database - Query and display.

However, the data in the Linux server is constantly updating, so I need real-time update.

Can anyone tell me what are the other methods available to perform that?

Comment: Try to add some relevant details like the type of data, e.g., log files. You would require a server-side programming language like Python or PHP which can read the data and display it on a webpage. Since the data is constantly updating then using node.js can be a good option.

Comment: yes its a log file. can you show me what are the functions in php to perform that?

Comment: Check this repo for guidance https://github.com/mthenw/frontail. Your question is pretty specific and doesn't add value for others so it'd be better if you delete it.